# How to draw parallel lines using an arc

Tags: arc

Does anybody know how to draw the right vertical line parallel to the left vertical line?

**CODE:**

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    
       \draw[step=1ex,black!10,thin] (-4ex,-20ex) grid (15ex,50ex);
    
       \draw (0ex,0ex) arc [start angle=135, end angle=405, radius=6ex] -- (7ex,50ex) -- (0ex,50ex) -- (0ex,0ex);

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were very close to desired solution. Try the following:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[step=1ex,black!10,thin] (-4ex,-12ex) grid ++ (16ex,64ex);
%
\draw (0,0) arc [start angle=135, end angle=405, radius=6ex] -- ++ (0,50ex) -| cycle;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Difference between your and mine solution is use of the relative and orthogonal coordinates.

Comment: thx a lot. very elegant solution!